# Function to check whether the user is at the top level of the network?

Tags: multisite

I need a conditional to check to whether or not to execute code at the top level of network admin pages: `/wp-admin/network`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(is_super_admin() && is_network_admin()){
    // do network admin only code
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin

http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/24/is_network_admin/